# PHP | Регулярные вражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, laravel, валидация

Как правильно составить регулярное выражение для моей цели?

У меня есть строка:

```
Жанр1, жанр2, жанр3, жанр4
```

Мне надо пройти валидацию с помощью регулярного выражения. Я написал вот таоке:

> [a-zA-Zа-яА-Яё-]+,

Все бы хорошо, но это работает только на примере строки. Если использовать реальные данные, например:

> второй шанс, в этот же мир, перерождение, хитрость и обман

То, вместо массива:

```
[
    'второй шанс'
    'в этот же мир'
    'перерождение'
    'хитрость и обман'
]
```

Я получу:

```
[
    'шанс'
    'мир'
    'перерождение'
    'обман'
]
```

Надеюсь, я объяснил свою проблему максимально понятно.

**UPD:** необходимо получить ВСЕ, кроме пробелов ВОКРУГ запятых и самих запятых.

Comment: `[\sa-zA-Zа-яА-Яё-]+,`?

Comment: Так он берет и пустые пробелы в начале выражения, чего я хотел избежать. Иначе я мог бы просто сделать explode(',').

Comment: Дайте точное описание, про пробелы в начале ничего не сказано в вопросе

Comment: Исправил, чтобы не возникало подобных недопониманий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
[\p{L}-—]+(?:\h[\p{L}-—]+)*(?=,)?
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/ojQ1Hy/3:

> **втор-ой шанс**, **в эт—от же мир**, **перерождение**, **хитрость и обман**

Сгенерированный код:

```
$re = '/[\p{L}-—]+(?:\h[\p{L}-—]+)*(?=,)?/m';
$str = '  втор-ой шанс, в эт—от же мир, перерождение, хитрость и обман';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Да, это почти подходит. Но как туда добавить ещё **-** **—** и т.п?

Comment: @SireIMPACTUS обновил для этих двух символов

Comment: спасибо, ты спас мне пару часов минимум.

Comment: Странно. preg_match_all() вместо готовых словосочетаний выдает мне по буквам. Даже пробовал code generator сайта: preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);, все равно выдает по буквам. Есть идеи, что делать?

Comment: Не знаю PHP, могу помочь только с регулярными выражениями, а код c++/python. Лучше задайте новый вопрос по коду

Comment: Как оказалось, проблема в регулярке. Не знаю, как на других языках, но php не любит p{L}, поэтому надо изменить немного.

Comment: @SireIMPACTUS замените его на `a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ` тогда, но `\p{L}` должно работать в PCRE грамматике

Comment: Не обязательно так. Достаточно (pL-—), результат тот же. Отправил модерам правку.

Comment: @SireIMPACTUS лучше дайте новый ответ, если считаете, что этот неверен. В PHP может это и работает, но в онлайн-инструментах - нет

Comment: В этом нет необходимости. Ваш ответ верен, просто нужно его дополнить и уточнить, что в случае с php необходимо поправить выражение.

Comment: @SireIMPACTUS вы же понимаете, что я не могу включить в свой ответ информацию по языку, который не знаю? Более того, проверка регулярки с `(pL-—)` в онлайн-инструментах у меня выдаёт неверный результат

Comment: Да, ты прав. У меня получался результат, но, как оказалось, он не был до конца верен. Использовал твой вариант и все заработало правильно. Я даже расширил выражение до /[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9+-]+(?:\h[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ0-9+-]+)*(?=,)?/m